# Setting default value for point column

Tags: mysql, geolocation, default-value

How to set a default value for Point column on MYSQL table

I tried

```
`location` POINT NULL DEFAULT POINT(7.0, 81.0),
```

but gives an error

> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'POINT(7.0, 81.0),

How to set default value to Point Column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A column with type `POINT` cannot have a default value.

if you run `create table x(`location`POINT not null DEFAULT 7.0, 81.0)` you will see the message

> BLOB/TEXT column 'location' can't have a default value

You can refer to [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Is there any reference on this.I found
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1238838&seqNum=2

Which was written on 2008

Comment: I can't add a special index if there is no default value! so what's wrong?

Comment: I'm running into this problem and I haven't found any solution other than to make sure I specify a value myself.  I.e. in any code written in another language that interfaces with the database and creates an entry in the appropriate table, I have the code insert the desired default value manually.  It feels like a "hack" or poor solution, and I wish default values for points were implemented, but it works.

Comment: Alternatively, MariaDB (from v. 10.2.1 onward) supports defaults for BLOB/TEXT columns, and is (mostly) backwards compatible with MySQL.